# Upgrade Symfony 2.8 to 3.4

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am looking how to upgrade the framework Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 without internet.

Can I configure the `composer.json` to upgrade Symfony from a local repository?

My development environment doesn't have access to internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.4 using local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251375/upgrade-symfony-2-8-to-3-4-using-local-directory) (this is the same user)

Answer (score 0):

If you have symfony code locally - as well as any other vendor code - you can configure composer in order to update from local source

```
"repositories": [
 {
  "type": "vcs",
  "url" : "/path/to/local/sf/code"
 }
],
```

Please remember to get rid of this as soon as you're ready to retrieve the vendor from the internet.

Comment: What did you mean by "symfony code" ? Framework or project code ? I want to upgrade Symfony Framework. I have not a Project code for the moment.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. BTW I mean symfony framework code, not your project