# upgrade symfony 2.8 to 3.4 using local directory

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am looking how to upgrade the framework Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 using local directory.
My development environment doesn't have access to internet.

I've followed https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

I download Symfony 3.4 and deposit it in the same directory as Synfony 2.8

```
Frameworks 
    Symfony-2.8
    Symfony-3.4
```

Then I configured the composer.json file (symfony 2.8) like this :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url" : "/frameworks/symfony3-4"
    }
],
 "require": {
        "/frameworks/symfony3-4": "*"
},
```

When I try the update :

```
Composer update
```

I have this error :

```
Problem 1
  - The requested package ../symfony3-4 could not be found in any version, there
 may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 A typo in the package name
 The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
 see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Do you have any suggestion to do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your "require" name should be the same as "name" in composer.json inside your "/frameworks/symfony3-4" directory.

Comment: What do you mean ? can you give me the syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

use  `"symfony/symfony": "^3.0"` in your require statement

Comment: "require": { "symfony/symfony": "^3.0" }, I have a new error :  Problem 1 :
   - The requested package symfony/symfony ^3.0 exists as symfony/symfony[v2.8.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Comment: I added { "packagist": false } to "repositories" to desable updating from web. I steel have the same error.

Comment: Try removing composer.lock, that usually helps. If not, I'd try removing /vendor as well